# Python 3.1 NameError headache

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python 3.1, and working my way through it on PyScripter.

Everything seemed to be going well until a program I'd written worked fine when executed in PyScripter, but failed when run in the cmd window. Rather than include all of the code I've isolated the problem to a piece including the input() function.

Here's what I have:

```
myname = input('? ')
print (myname)
input ('Press any key to end')
```

This works fine in PyScripter, I type in my name, hit Return and the name appears, but when I try to run it in the cmd window I get the following result:

```
F:\Python_Programs\input.py
? Fenton
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Python_Programs\input.py", line 17, in <module>
     myname = input('? ')
  File "<string>" line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Fenton' is not defined`
```

Any ideas?

Comment: By the way, 3.1 (while not as horribly outdated and flawed as 3.0) is two major versions behind. You get the worst of both worlds: No 2.x compatibility, but only a fraction of the awesome new stuff. Any reason to not use 3.2 or 3.3?

Answer (score 4):

Your "command window" is using Python 2 rather than 3. In version 2, you should use `raw_input`.

Comment: The solution is probably more to change the file association for `.py` files than to give up and use Python 2 syntax instead.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I just discovered that myself by inserting import sys
print (sys.version_info) into the code. It looks like the cmd is using the version 2.7 I installed previously. I tried to delete my question but was unable to because you had already replied. Thanks for taking the time to do so.